# XML mapping with java

Tags: java, xml, mapping

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ROOT>
    <fieldset>
        <field Id="c0" Name="_ID_VERSION" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c1" Name="_TYPE" DataType="string"/>
        <field Id="c2" Name="_PRODUCT" DataType="string"/>
        <field Id="c3" Name="_VERSION" DataType="string"/>
        <field Id="c4" Name="_REVISION" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c5" Name="_STATE" DataType="string"/>
        <field Id="c6" Name="_DOCUMENT" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c7" Name="_HAS_LINK" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c8" Name="_LOCKED" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c9" Name="_ACCESSLEVEL" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c10" Name="_LABEL" DataType="int"/>
        <field Id="c11" Name="_LABEL_NAME" DataType="string"/>
    </fieldset>
    <rowset>
        <row c0="2932" c1="" c2="{3FDAC10D-5361-4C32-B79E-D391DCB3AE98}" c3="" c4="0" c5="" c6="0" c7="1" c8="0" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>
        <row c0="3146" c1="0" c2="MyProject" c3="" c4="0" c5="" c6="0" c7="1" c8="1" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>
        <row c0="3147" c1="" c2="tes" c3="" c4="0" c5="" c6="0" c7="1" c8="0" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>
        <row c0="2933" c1="" c2="" c3="" c4="0" c5="" c6="0" c7="1" c8="0" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>
        <row c0="3048" c1="" c2="" c3="" c4="0" c5="" c6="0" c7="1" c8="0" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>
    </rowset>
</ROOT>
```

How to I can map this text to POJO in java? I have tried parsing it with the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document document = null;
try {
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(incomming));
    document = db.parse(is);
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return document;
```

But I want to do it automatically.

Comment: This: `<row c0="3147" c1="0?:0 :>=B@035=B>2" c2="tes" c3="" c4="0" c5="!CI5AB2C5B" c6="0" c7="1" c8="0" c9="3" c10="-1" c11=""/>` does not look like valid XML.

Comment: Sorry xml prettify error encode it

Comment: What should your pojo look like?

Comment: Do you have a schema? Do you want to get something with properties `idVersion`, `type`, `product` etc. or `fieldset`, `rowset` etc?

Comment: not i don't schema file. Yes it API out from programm. I want convert it to pogo for work with it in next steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question probably hits most of the SO offtopic list. :) Recommend-a-tool, opinion-based, what-have-you-tried-so-far-etc. But, hey, whatever. :)

Here's an opinion-based tool recommendation of what I like, namely [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/).

Write and annotate your POJOS:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
public class Dataset {

  @XmlElementWrapper(name="fieldset")
  @XmlElement(name="field")
  public List<Field> fields = new LinkedList<Field>();

  @XmlElementWrapper(name="rowset")
  @XmlElement(name="row")
  public List<Row> rows = new LinkedList<Row>();

}

public class Field {
  @XmlElement(name="Id")
  public String id;
  @XmlElement(name="Name")
  public String name;
  @XmlElement(name="DataType")
  public String dataType;
}

public class Row {
  @XmlAnyElement
  public Map<QName, String> columns = new HashMap<QName, String>();
}
```

Create a `JAXBContext` for your POJOs:

```
final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dataset.class);
```

"Parsing" in JAXB is called "unmarshalling:

```
final Unmarshaller = contect.createUnmarshaller();
final Dataset dataset = (Dataset) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
```

I just sketched the code right here, so this won't probably work from the very start, but you get the idea.

I am also not sure that these are the POJOs you want, but it might be good to start with.

Apart from JAXB, there's probably a few dozens other libraries you could use for the task. Please don't take JAXB as the only answer, check alternatives as well.